# loading a graph with till Depth N in main memory in java

Tags: graph, orientdb

How to load a entire graph rooted at vertex V in java ?

I have a veertex V which is root node.Now this is connected to Some other vertex which intern is connected to more vertices and so on.

I want to load entire graph till depth N.

Is possible?

```
public class GraphLoader{

   public void loadGraph(RootID id){
      //load here
      //What will be return type ??Vertex??I mean class of rootNode?
   }

}

1)How can i to it using native libs? <br>
2)How can i do it using ThinkerPop bluprientAPI
```

I am not in favour of get a vertex from vertex then geting next then next.This will take long time.
My graph is of depth around 100 and number of nodes may be many

Answer (score 0):

About (1) lok at [OrientDB Java Traverse](https://github.com/nuvolabase/orientdb/wiki/Java-Traverse).